# "I went for shopping"

Tags: prepositions

I would like to know about the following two usages:

1. I went shopping yesterday.
2. I went for shopping yesterday.

I know that the first sentence is definitely correct but is sentence 2 correct as well? Why or why not?

Comment: No, the second one must be "I went for a shop yesterday" or "I went shopping for [noun] yesterday".

Comment: Shoppping has a meaning of the act of purchasing. The second one is correct. But, why use a preposition when it is absolutely useless?

Comment: In AmE, I don't think we'd say "went for a shop". We might say "I went **on** a shopping trip." just as you might go "**on** a tour"

Comment: related: [What is the origin of “GO + VERB + ING”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/253849/what-is-the-origin-of-go-verb-ing)

Comment: In BrE I might say " I went for the shopping yesterday", we sometimes use the " shopping " in a similar way that Americans use groceries.

Answer (score 1):

The second is incorrect. 
You may say, "I went shopping for [object] yesterday."
E.g. "I went shopping for apples yesterday."

In a comment I see that someone has indicated that "I went for a shop yesterday" is okay usage. This may be the case colloquially in some places, but I'm not familiar with the usage.

Answer (score -1):

the Second Sentence is when you go shopping for something
if you just want to talk about shopping you may have to use the first one:)

Comment: Wrong.  The second sentence is incorrect, as stated in the other answer.